# Do Cooked Leeks Cause Bad Body Odour

Tags: smell, cook, leeks

Like in the question, do cooked leeks cause bad body odour and breath?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but only to the extent that all alliums do.  Leeks, like onions and garlic, are high in sulfur, and [sulfur compounds can contribute to unpleasant body odors](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/symptoms/17865-body-odor).

Comment: It is only unpleasant if both parties don't smell like it. If all people in the house like garlic then the unpleasant smell just becomes the 'smell'.